# Rpi Zero - Snappy Ubuntu Core

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w, ubuntu

Ubuntu Core is meant to be a very light OS, which is ideal for RPi zero.
Today I run a RPi Zero using Raspbian Stretch Lite, but I would be happy to run even lighter OS, as Ubuntu Core.

What is the reason for not enabling it to be installed on the Pi Zero?

Is there a way to install it?

Comment: I don't know.  What do the maintainers of Ubuntu Core say?

Comment: https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3

Comment: So the Pi Zero isn't supported.  You need to ask the maintainers why.

Comment: @joan edited : is there a way to install ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ubuntu core is meant to be a VERY light OS, which is ideal for RPI zero.

It's no "lighter" than Raspbian lite in terms of e.g., RAM consumption -- which is really a matter of how you configure the system, **not** the distro you choose.

It may be lighter in terms of how much space the base image requires (Raspbian lite is ~1.8 GB), but since you provide the SD card, this has nothing to do with which model you use.  You could put a big card in a Zero just like you could put it in a 3B+.

> What is the reason for not enabling it to be installed on Rpi Zero ?

Because the single core Pi's have an ARMv6 processor, which was arguably a bit outdated when the Pi was released (it was in fact 10 years old in 2013 -- [ARM1176JZ(F)-S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM11#Overview) is the ARMv6 implementation used).

All of the existing Pi distributions, including Raspbian, are essentially tweaks of parent distributions that were not created specifically for the Pi -- they are for generic ARM targets.  I believe the only GNU/Linux outfit to maintain an ARMv6 distro is Debian, and this is what Raspbian is based on.

Most of the GNU/Linux organizations, including Ubuntu, have ARMv7 distros, since there are many more ARMv7 devices around (including the multi-core Pis).  But they do not have an ARMv6 one.

Comment: thank you for you reply. Lighter - since almost no process are running in background , which is more preferable to me.

Comment: That is a matter of how you configure the system...and like I said, I don't believe Ubuntu uses any less RAM by default.  Raspbian lite loads at 50 - 100 MB, which is normal for a headless Linux distro.  *Now they are all using systemd, the differences between them are trivial.*  Although: Ubuntu Core does look to have some unusual and desirable features, but they are not about "lightness".